# Remove cyan highlighting in Scintilla JavaScript lexer

Tags: .net, scintilla

I have an instance of Scintilla working in .NET, but there is something in the JavaScript lexer that I'd like to remove. It is the cyan/green background when replacing something between apostrophies. I think this image shows it clearly enough:

[click here, I'm new so I cannot post the image here](http://piczasso.com/i/nn7v1.png)

I cannot find this color anywhere in my editor's properties. Does somebody know how to remove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript highlighting is based on the C++ highlighting, so these two effect JavaScript strings for me:

```
# Double quoted string
style.cpp.6=$(colour.string)
# Single quoted string
style.cpp.7=$(colour.char)
```

There's also a style which highlights unterminated strings, which may be what you're after

```
# End of line where string is not closed
style.cpp.12=fore:#000000,$(font.monospace),back:#E0C0E0,eolfilled
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I access style.cpp? In fact, I cannot tell which language you're using here - I'm using VB.NET with Scintilla.NET, which one are you using?

Comment: @pimvdb That's from SciTE config files. It should be similar for other scintilla uses - find where styles 6,7,12 have their colours set in your system, and set their values to what you prefer.

Comment: I finally found it, it wasn't too complicated in the end: `Editor.Styles(12).BackColor = Color.White` makes it white. Thanks!